# Tflite custom model failed to run in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, tensorflow, machine-learning, augmented-reality

I'm doing an augmented image app in Flutter and for the image detection I'm using Tflite. I did my own model with Teachable Machine, exported it and put it in an assets folder.

So I did that in my pubsec.yaml :

```
assets:
    - assets/labels.txt
    - assets/model_unquant.tflite
```

And this :

```
tflite: ^1.1.2
camera: ^0.9.4+16
```

But I got the error :

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
```

Do you know how to fix it ? Thank you